# Did Kanade Oe break the "4th wall"?

Tags: chihayafuru

In episode 7 of **Chihayafuru 2**, Chihaya mentions that she didn't know what "Frenzied" means and Kanade says to herself:

> "We're in the second season and she still doesn't know what the title means?!"

[image]

I realize that "chihayaburu" is impassionate, but is this a play on words somehow? Or is this an instance of Kanade breaking the fourth wall? It would be the first instance of this happening as far as I know, seemed really awkward and out of place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though it's not explicitly stated either way (imagine in a series, if they were to mention that they broke the fourth-wall; that's some serious meta fourth-wall-breaking), the general consensus in the fan kingdom is that this is an instance of the 4th wall being broken.

As you mentioned, *chihayaburu* ([千早振る](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%83%E6%97%A9%E6%8C%AF%E3%82%8B)) a [*makurakotoba*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makurakotoba) meaning "wild"<sup>[[1]](http://fudoan.cdx.jp/english/bugei_e/fudoan_dojo/chihaya.htm)</sup> or "vigorous power"<sup>[[2]](http://vetus.wordpress.com/astrape/)</sup>, which can be synonymous with "impassioned" or "frenzied". So, in English, it's not unlikely that the word "frenzied" could be (loosely) considered the title.

As I mentioned, though, there are several unofficial sources (some fans, some not) mentioning this (sudden) break in the fourth wall.<sup>[[3]](http://www.lostinanime.com/2013/02/chihayafuru-2-07.html)[[4]](http://www.limitofquestions.com/2013/02/chihayafuru-2-7.html)[[5]](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=562147#msg20186017)[[6]](http://ar-machine.net/forums/showthread.php?tid=467&pid=88938#pid88938)</sup> So, based on the closeness of the words, and the fan/community reaction to it, this seems to be a "breaking the fourth wall" scenario.